# Rails ActiveRecord Serializer not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, serialization

I have a few serializers set up in my app and recently decided to create another one for a new feature. This one is nearly identical to the others, except that the model/attributes are different. I'm not sure why, but no matter what I do, Rails doesn't seem to detect that I have a serializer for my model and bypasses it. Even if I just put in a bunch of gibberish code that should raise an exception, Rails delivers a JSON response with all the attributes of my model. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I referenced [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers?view=asciicast) to see if I missed a step, but as far as I can tell, everything looks right.

Here is my `app/serializers/job_description_serializer.rb`:

```
class JobDescriptionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id,
        :title,
        :role,
        :description,
        :posting_link,
        :company_id,
        :company_name,
        :created_at,
        :updated_at

    def company_name
        object.company.name
    end
end
```

Here is my `jobs_controller.rb`. I've tried this without the `root: false` argument as well.

```
class Admin::JobsController < ApplicationController
    layout 'admin'

    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :authenticate_admin
    def index
        @job_descriptions = JobDescription.all
        @total_count = @job_descriptions.count

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render action: 'index' }
            format.json { render json: { jobs: @job_descriptions, total_count: @total_count }, root: false }
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMS accepts a meta keyword for displaying total_count and any other meta data,

```
format.json { render json: @job_descriptions, meta: { total_count: @total_count } }
```

Comment: That didn't have any effect. I also renamed the controller to `JobDescriptionsController` / `job_descriptions_controller.rb` to see if that might be a problem, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Strange. If I change my respond_to block to `format.json { render json: @job_descriptions }` it works perfectly, but now I'm missing my `total_count`.

Comment: I just submitted an edit to your code. I got it to work with `meta` after I removed `root: false`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Instead of passing `render json:` a nested hash as I was doing before, I pushed `{ total_count: @total_count }` into `@job_descriptions` like so:

```
format.json { render json: @job_descriptions << { total_count: @total_count }, root: false }
```

Works perfectly now. I think the problem is that you can't use a serializer on a nested hash like IW as trying to do, or maybe you can, but I'm not sure how.